# Points of local minima of a convex function is a point of global minima, and points of minima form a convex set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis

> Show that every point of local minima of a convex function is a point
>   of global minima. Also, show that the set of minimum points is convex.

If $x*$ is a point of local minima of $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}                $, then, for some $p$, it's always valid $|x-x^*|<p \implies f(x^*)\le f(x)$.

If $f$ is convex, then:

$$f((1-t)x+ty)\le (1-t)f(x) + tf(y)$$

for all $t\in[0,1], x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$

I kinda understood the argument here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1280231/166180. Basicaly, it supposes that there exists a point $f(x_0)< f(x*)$ where $x*$ is the original local minimum point. Then it does:

$$f((1-t)x^*+tx_0) \le (1-t)f(x^*)+tf(x_0)< (1-t)f(x^*)+tf(x^*) = f(x^*)$$

But remember the condition  $|x-x^*|<p \implies f(x^*)\le f(x)$? If I choose $t$ in the right way, we see that it's valid that $f(something)$ where that something is $(1-t)x^*+tx_0$ is indeed $<f(x^*)$ so $x^*$ is not our global minima. Turns out that there exists such $t$. **Am I right?**

**Now, in order to show that the set of minimum points is convex**, I need to show that if $a$ and $b$ are two minimum points, then $(1-t)a+tb$ is also a minimum point for all $t\in [0,1]$.

If $a$ and $b$ are minimum points, then there exists $p_1,p_2$ such that it's always valid: $|x-a|<p_1 \implies f(a)<f(x)$ and $|x-b|<p_2 \implies f(b)<f(x)$. I think I must show that there exists $p_3$ such that

$$|x-((1-t)a+tb)|<p_3\implies f((1-t)a+tb)<f(x)$$

for all $t\in [0,1]$

I can at least see that $f((1-t)a+tb)\le (1-t)f(a)+tf(b)<f(a)+f(b)< 2f(x)$

I whish I could take $p_1$ and $p_2$ such that $|x-a|<p_1\implies f(a)<f(x)/2 + \cdots$ but this is not possible, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started by showing that local minima are global minima.
Then, if $a$ and $b$ are minima points, it follows that $f(a) = f(b)$ (they're both global minima).
So $$f((1-t)a + tb) \leq (1-t)f(a) + tf(b) = (1-t)f(a) + tf(a) = f(a),$$ 
and it follows that $(1-t)a + tb$ is also a minimum point.